# Python - Excel row background based on value (Multiple values that must be identified)

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file in the following format:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yesterday | 70 | today | 70 |
| yesterday | 71 | today | 71 |

The goal here is to compare today's data with yesterday's data with the same ID (70 and 71 in this example), there is a blank row splitting different IDs.

This data is automatically generated and saved in an excel file with multiple sheets (one for each category), so what I want to do is to just automatically change row background to a random light color (1 for each automatically identified ID) to help better separate distinct IDs.

Not sure how to get these random colors, nor how to correctly identify each row and change its background.

Comment: There are a few different ways to solve to approach this goal but it would help if you could include some code attempts. Do you know how many distinct IDs you expect to have? With the current info, I would recommend looking into Openpyxl, https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using the "openpyxl" library

```
import openpyxl
import random

# Load the Excel file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')

# Loop through each sheet in the workbook
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
    # Select the sheet
    ws = wb[sheet]
    
    # Loop through each row in the sheet
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        # Check if the row contains yesterday's data
        if row[2].value == 'yesterday':
            # Get the ID value
            id_value = row[3].value
            
            # Loop through each row again to find today's data with the same ID
            for row2 in ws.iter_rows():
                if row2[2].value == 'today' and row2[3].value == id_value:
                    # Set the background color of both rows to a random light color
                    color = '00' + ''.join(random.choices('0123456789ABCDEF', k=6))
                    row[0].fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(start_color=color, end_color=color, fill_type='solid')
                    row2[0].fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(start_color=color, end_color=color, fill_type='solid')

# Save the modified Excel file
wb.save('example_modified.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks mate!

It worked wonders, I just changed a bit to better work on my df (Many rows with the same IDs and different days).

Thank you for your help :)